# Combine entries from two lists by position using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Say I have two lists with following entries

```
List<int> a = new List<int> { 1, 2, 5, 10 };
List<int> b = new List<int> { 6, 20, 3 };
```

I want to create another List c where its entries are items inserted by position from two lists. So List c would contain the following entries:

```
List<int> c = {1, 6, 2, 20, 5, 3, 10}
```

Is there a way to do it in .NET using LINQ? I was looking at .Zip() LINQ extension, but wasn't sure how to use it in this case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want: item from list 1, followed by item from list 2, followed by next item from list 1, and so on? And what to do in case either list contains fewer elements? Just dump out the rest of the other list? ie. if the lists are `a1, a2, a3` and `b1, b2, b3, b4, b5` you want `a1, b1, a2, b2, a3, b3, b4, b5`?

Comment: And since you're asking if there is a way to do it in .NET using Linq, do you want just a "Yes" or "No" answer, do you *only* want LINQ solutions, or do you want readable code?

Comment: Because there *is* a way to do it in .NET using LINQ.

Comment: Exactly. I want an item from list 1, followed by item from list 2 (same index). Let's also assume that List 2 count will always <= than count of items in List 1. I'd like a LINQ solution, hopefully somewhat readable. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I merge (or zip) two IEnumerables together?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682904/how-do-i-merge-or-zip-two-ienumerables-together)

Comment: FYI, the `Zip` extension method won't do what you want...quoting from the MSDN article: `"The method merges each element of the first sequence with an element that has the same index in the second sequence. If the sequences do not have the same number of elements, the method merges sequences until it reaches the end of one of them. For example, if one sequence has three elements and the other one has four, the result sequence will have only three elements."`

Comment: This is the case when the old but gold foreach loop would give a more readable result... Why are you requiring Linq?

Comment: I wanted to use LINQ for simplicity. Sure foreach loop would work, but I wanted to find out if there is an easy answer using LINQ.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To do it using LINQ, you can use this piece of [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) example code:

```
void Main()
{
    List<int> a = new List<int> { 1, 2, 5, 10 };
    List<int> b = new List<int> { 6, 20, 3 };

    var result = Enumerable.Zip(a, b, (aElement, bElement) => new[] { aElement, bElement })
        .SelectMany(ab => ab)
        .Concat(a.Skip(Math.Min(a.Count, b.Count)))
        .Concat(b.Skip(Math.Min(a.Count, b.Count)));

    result.Dump();
}
```

Output:

[image: LINQPad example output]

This will:

- Zip the two lists together (which will stop when either runs out of elements)
- Producing an array containing the two elements (one from a, another from b)
- Using `SelectMany` to "flatten" this out to one sequence of values
- Concatenate in the remainder from either list (only one or neither of the two calls to Concat should add any elements)

---

**Now**, having said that, personally I would've used this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Intertwine<T>(this IEnumerable<T> a, IEnumerable<T> b)
{
    using (var enumerator1 = a.GetEnumerator())
    using (var enumerator2 = b.GetEnumerator())
    {
        bool more1 = enumerator1.MoveNext();
        bool more2 = enumerator2.MoveNext();

        while (more1 && more2)
        {
            yield return enumerator1.Current;
            yield return enumerator2.Current;

            more1 = enumerator1.MoveNext();
            more2 = enumerator2.MoveNext();
        }

        while (more1)
        {
            yield return enumerator1.Current;
            more1 = enumerator1.MoveNext();
        }

        while (more2)
        {
            yield return enumerator2.Current;
            more2 = enumerator2.MoveNext();
        }
    }
}
```

Reasons:

- It doesn't enumerate `a` nor `b` more than once
- I'm skeptical about the performance of `Skip`
- It can work with any `IEnumerable<T>` and not just `List<T>`

Comment: I really like the second solution. Looks exactly what I need plus the extension method can be very handy. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah. I +1ed already but this is nicer. And I doubt skip is that worth worrying about performance wise but it will I would imagine cause a or b to enumerate more than once. I doubt there is any performance hit beyond that (which you covered in the first bullet point).

Comment: Doesn't `.Zip()` expect the same number of elements on both lists?

Answer (score 3):

I'd create an extension method to do it.

```
public static List<T> MergeAll<T>(this List<T> first, List<T> second)
{
    int maxCount = (first.Count > second. Count) ? first.Count : second.Count;
    var ret = new List<T>();
    for (int i = 0; i < maxCount; i++)
    {
        if (first.Count < maxCount)
            ret.Add(first[i]);
        if (second.Count < maxCount)
            ret.Add(second[i]);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

This would iterate through both lists once. If one list is bigger than the other it will continue to add until it's done.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this code:

```
List<int> c = a.Select((i, index) => new Tuple<int, int>(i, index * 2))
               .Union(b.Select((i, index) => new Tuple<int, int>(i, index * 2 + 1)))
               .OrderBy(t => t.Second)
               .Select(t => t.First).ToList();
```

It makes a union of two collections and then sorts that union using index. Elements from the first collection have even indices, from the second - odd ones.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrote a little extension for this:

```
public static class MyEnumerable
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Smash<T>(this IEnumerable<T> one, IEnumerable<T> two)
    {
        using (IEnumerator<T> enumeratorOne = one.GetEnumerator(), 
                              enumeratorTwo = two.GetEnumerator())
        {
            bool twoFinished = false;

            while (enumeratorOne.MoveNext())
            {
                yield return enumeratorOne.Current;

                if (!twoFinished && enumeratorTwo.MoveNext())
                {
                    yield return enumeratorTwo.Current;
                }
            }

            if (!twoFinished)
            {
                while (enumeratorTwo.MoveNext())
                {
                    yield return enumeratorTwo.Current;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var a = new List<int> { 1, 2, 5, 10 };
var b = new List<int> { 6, 20, 3 };

var c = a.Smash(b); // 1, 6, 2, 20, 5, 3, 10

var d = b.Smash(a); // 6, 1, 20, 2, 3, 5, 10
```

This will work for any `IEnumerable` so you can also do:

```
var a = new List<string> { "the", "brown", "jumped", "the", "lazy", "dog" };
var b = new List<string> { "quick", "dog", "over" };

var c = a.Smash(b); // the, quick, brown, fox, jumped, over, the, lazy, dog
```

Comment: Variable `twoFinished` will never become `true`.

Comment: Good spot. Feel free to modify!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Concat` and an anonymous type which you order by the index:

```
List<int> c = a
    .Select((val, index) => new { val, index })
    .Concat(b.Select((val, index) => new { val, index }))
    .OrderBy(x => x.index)
    .Select(x => x.val)
    .ToList();
```

However, since that's not really elegant and also less efficient than:

```
c = new List<int>(a.Count + b.Count);
int max = Math.Max(a.Count, b.Count);
int aMax = a.Count;
int bMax = b.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
{ 
    if(i < aMax)
        c.Add(a[i]);
    if(i < bMax)
        c.Add(b[i]);
}
```

I wouldn't use LINQ at all.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for adding a third extension method inspired by the other two, but I like it shorter:

```
static IEnumerable<T> Intertwine<T>(this IEnumerable<T> a, IEnumerable<T> b)
{
    using (var enumerator1 = a.GetEnumerator())
    using (var enumerator2 = b.GetEnumerator()) {
        bool more1 = true, more2 = true;
        do {
            if (more1 && (more1 = enumerator1.MoveNext()))
                yield return enumerator1.Current;
            if (more2 && (more2 = enumerator2.MoveNext()))
                yield return enumerator2.Current;
        } while (more1 || more2);
    }
}
```