# Merge lists without putting populants of the new list on new lines

Tags: c#, list, gtfs

I want to merge two lists together, but the methods I've found add the list's populants to new lines, like this.

```
parts on list one,
parts on list one,
parts on list one,
parts on list two,
parts on list two,
parts on list two,
```

However, I want it to look like this.

```
parts on list one,parts on list two
parts on list one,parts on list two
parts on list one,parts on list two
```

This is what I have to merge them them (+ the lists themselves so far)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        iterateRoutes(@"C:\Users\peepee poopoo\gtfs\routes.txt", @"C:\Users\peepee poopoo\gtfs\calendar.txt");
        //log.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
    }

    public static List<string> log = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> datesStd = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> datesEnd = new List<string>();

    public static void iterateRoutes(string rtname, string std)
    {
        foreach (var route in File.ReadAllLines(rtname)) // iterate file lines
        {
            var elements = route.Split(','); // split current line into elements
            log.Add(elements[0] + "," + elements[2] + "," + "2021426,20991231,"); // add first & third element to log
        }

        foreach (var route in File.ReadAllLines(std)) // iterate file lines
        {
            //var elements = route.Split(','); // split current line into elements
            //log.Add("," + elements[8]); // add first & third element to log
        }



        //datesStd.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
        // datesEnd.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

        log.AddRange(datesStd);
        log.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
    }
```

How could I do this?

Comment: If you're using `foreach` like this, you should use `File.ReadLines` instead of `File.ReadAllLines`. `File.ReadLines` will load the next line of the file as it needs it, whereas `File.ReadAllLines` will read the entire thing into memory before looping.

Comment: @Llama It's a lot faster, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Also, [this might answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3781057/3181933).

Comment: @Llama What does the `(first, second)` represent in the resource you provided? I can't figure this out.

Comment: On the first iteration, `first = 1; second = "one"`, on the second `first = 2; second = "two"`, and so on (based on the sample data in that answer).

Comment: @Llama Nothing's working, I still don't understand any of this

Answer (score 0):

To join the files you can use zip:

```
IEnumerable<string> fileOne = File.ReadLines("one.txt");
IEnumerable<string> fileTwo = File.ReadLines("two.txt");

// For each line in fileOne, take a line from fileTwo
// call these lines l1 and l2 respectively, and produce 
// a merged result.
IEnumerable<string> joined = fileOne.Zip(fileTwo, (l1, l2) => $"{l1}{l2}");

// write the result to a file
File.WriteAllLines("out.txt", joined);

// or materialize it to a list
List<string> lines = joined.ToList();
```

[Zip documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-5.0)

So if we have one file:

```
A
B
C
```

And another file:

```
D
E
F
```

Then the result will be

```
AD
BE
CF
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/JFOQ66890). Note that I've replaced `File.ReadLines` with my own fake version here, since the site I'm using doesn't support reading files.