# How can i group those enumerables?

Tags: c#

For example, if i have:

```
var keys = new[] {"AAA", "AAA", "BBB", "BBB", "BBB"};
var valueA = new[] {"2", "1", "6", "5", "2"};
var valueB = new[] {"Hello", "World", "Foo", "Bar", "Baz"};
```

then i want group then like this:

```
{
  { // Group AAA
    ("2", "Hello"),
    ("1", "World"),
  },
  { // Group BBB
    ("6", "Foo"),
    ("5", "Bar"),
    ("2", "Baz")
  }
}
```

How can i make it?

Comment: and what did you try? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Maybe use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682904/how-do-i-merge-or-zip-two-ienumerables-together) / [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640881/how-to-use-zip-on-three-ienumerables) to build each matching triplet into an object (or tuple), and then group based on the key property?